# items in listview load not showing

Tags: vb.net, listview, ms-access-2003

i have a problem in viewing items in listview
this is my code

`rs.Open("select tableStudentRecords.*, tableTransaction.*, tablePayments.* from tableStudentRecords, tableTransaction , tablePayments" & _
               " where tableStudentRecords.studnum = tableTransaction.studnum and tablePayments.psitscode = tableTransaction.psitscode", con, 3, 3)
     Dim i As Integer = 0
        With lvPaymentRecords
            Do Until rec.EOF
                .Items.Add(rec("tableTransaction.studnum").Value)
                x = rec("sname").Value & ", " & rec("fname").Value & " " & rec("mi").Value & " " & rec("ext").Value
                .Items(i).SubItems.Add(x)
                lvPaymentRecords.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("sem").Value)
                .Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("sy").Value)
                .Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("total").Value)
                i = i + 1
                rec.MoveNext()
            Loop
        End With
        rec.Close()
        con.Close()`

the thing is, items wont appear in listview, i dont know what is the cause,
tableStudentRecords and tablePayments are both PRIMARY keys,
here is the database relationships
(im sorry i cant post the image due to less reputation)

**tableStudentRecords _____ tableTransaction  _____ tablePAyments**

-studnum  _____________ -psitscode _____________-psitscode

-sname _______________ -studnum ____________-sem

-fname ________________ -sy  __________________-payname

-gndr __________________-total _______________-amount

i only need to view the sem from tablePayments in listview load,

Comment: where is the code for the listview?

Comment: sorry, dont editting

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a ListViewItem variable. The codes should be

```
 Dim lpRec As ListViewItem
    With lvPaymentRecords
        Do Until rec.EOF
            lpRec=.Items.Add(rec("tableTransaction.studnum").Value)
            x = rec("sname").Value & ", " & rec("fname").Value & " " & rec("mi").Value & " " & rec("ext").Value
            lpRec.SubItems.Add(x)
            lpRec.SubItems.Add(rec("sem").Value)
            lpRec.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("sy").Value)
            lpRec.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("total").Value)
            i = i + 1
            rec.MoveNext()
        Loop
    End With
    rec.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Hope it can help you.